# Magento - Can not save second custom attribute to order with Observer

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I am developing an custom extension where i have to save two custom attributes when creating a new order. I have two custom inputs where you place the data.

While i am submitting data with the first input there is no problems, the data is saved and after that i can print it the admin order view page.

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <VivasIndustries_Vshippingone>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </VivasIndustries_Vshippingone>
    </modules>

    <global> 
         <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>                           
                <my_custom_input_field_one><to_order>*</to_order></my_custom_input_field_one>
                <my_custom_input_field_two><to_order>*</to_order></my_custom_input_field_two>
            </sales_convert_quote>

            <sales_convert_order>                                              
                <my_custom_input_field_one><to_quote>*</to_quote></my_custom_input_field_one>
                <my_custom_input_field_two><to_quote>*</to_quote></my_custom_input_field_two>
            </sales_convert_order>
        </fieldsets>
        <helpers>
            <vshippingone>
                <class>VivasIndustries_Vshippingone_Helper</class>
            </vshippingone>            
        </helpers>

        <models>
            <vshippingone>
                <class>VivasIndustries_Vshippingone_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>vshippingone_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </vshippingone>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <vshippingone_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>VivasIndustries_Vshippingone</module>
                    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </vshippingone_setup>
            <vshippingone_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </vshippingone_write>
            <vshippingone_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </vshippingone_read>
        </resources>

        <events>
            <checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
                 <observers>
                     <vshippingone>
                          <type>singleton</type>
                          <class>vshippingone/observer</class>
                          <method>saveCustomDataOne</method>
                     </vshippingone>
                 </observers>
            </checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
            <checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
                 <observers>
                     <vshippingone>
                          <type>singleton</type>
                          <class>vshippingone/observer</class>
                          <method>saveCustomDataTwo</method>
                     </vshippingone>
                 </observers>
            </checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>         
        </events>

        <blocks>
            <vshippingone>
                <class>VivasIndustries_Vshippingone_Block</class>
            </vshippingone>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Here is my Observer:

```
<?PHP
class VivasIndustries_Vshippingone_Model_Observer 
{
    public function saveCustomDataOne($event)
    {
        $quote = $event->getQuote();
        $quote->setData('my_custom_input_field_one', $event->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_address_id'));

        return $this;
    }
    public function saveCustomDataTwo($event)
    {
        $quote = $event->getQuote();
        $quote->setData('my_custom_input_field_two', $event->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_office'));

        return $this;
    }   
}
```

Somehow i am making something wrong with the second custom field. The data is not saved to the database. Where i my mistake and how can i make it save the data ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <events>
        <checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
             <observers>
                 <vshippingone>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>vshippingone/observer</class>
                      <method>saveCustomDataOne</method>
                 </vshippingone>
                 <vshippingtwo>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>vshippingone/observer</class>
                      <method>saveCustomDataTwo</method>
                 </vshippingtwo>
             </observers>
        </checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>         
    </events>
```

You had two observers called `vshippingone` and they can both be within the `checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method` tags

Comment: Do i have to create another Observer file ?

Comment: I don't think so, both of the methods you're calling (saveCustomDataOne and saveCustomDataTwo) are within the same class (VivasIndustries_Vshippingone_Model_Observer), so replacing what you current have between the `events` tags with what I've put above should work fine

Comment: It's still not saving data to the column `my_custom_input_field_two`. I do not understand where is my mistake.

Comment: Do you have cache enabled?

Comment: No. it is not enabled.